# How to open custom actions UITableviewrowaction in uitableviewcell programatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to open the swipe menu behind uitableviewcell without user swipe interaction, is this possible?

I tried calling  tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:
but no effect.

Comment: without any user interaction ? you mean when the table view is presented to the user it should show the actions directly along with the content ?

Comment: yes , when tableview is presented for first time, i show a tutorial screen which is animated, I want first row to slide automatically revealing the swipe menu below

Comment: @harshayarabarla any help?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately no, I am using a custom slidecell implementation which allows this and also works for iOS 7